# python parsing tab separated file

Tags: python

Fairly new to python

I want to parse a file with \t separated values, images below. How do i remove the \t from the file and seperate the values into columns?
Code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt"
s = requests.get(url).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJB6s.png)

[How i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUgEh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sep="\t"` into `pd.read_csv`. The data is messy, thus double tab needs to be replaced:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8').replace("\t\t", "\t")), 
    header=None, sep="\t")
```

Comment: It doesn't work, getting a ParserError:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-495590d67fdd> in <module>()
      4 url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt"
      5 s = requests.get(url).content
----> 6 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), sep="\t")
      7 df

Comment: @jkhammerseth Try again, please

Comment: You could separate on multiple tabs with regex e.g. `sep=r'\t+'`.

Answer (score 1):

If using csv library is an option you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt"
raw_data = requests.get(url).content
file = open("raw_data.txt","w")
file.write(raw_data)
data = list(csv.reader(open('raw_data.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print df
```